# Search files by a contained string and order them by size

Tags: linux, bash, search, grep, du

I need to get the biggest files which contain a certain string.
I found a way to list all the files that have that string:

```
grep -rwl '/tmp2disk' -e '{STRING}'
```

But I don't know how to order this list by size and get the biggest file.

Answer (score 2):

**grep** + **du** + **sort** pipeline:

```
grep -rwl '{STRING}' | xargs du -bh | sort -rh
```

---

- `xargs du -bh` - to estimate space usage of each file (in bytes)
- `sort -rh` - to sort the output numerically in descending order

Comment: `sort -rn`will sort by number, instead should be `sort -rh` to sort by human-readable number with units

Answer (score 1):

A small alternate version, rather using `xargs` you can do the followings:

```
 grep -Zrlw "directory" -e "string" | du -k --files0-from=- | sort -nr
```

- Using `--files0-from` option with `-` as param.
- `-Z` gives NUL terminated output; thus prepare the output for feeding `du`'s `--files0-from` option.